# Delay "no Javascript" warning from showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, warnings, noscript

I'm using the "noscript.js" file (detailed here: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/replacing-noscript-with-accessible-un/) to display a large (100+ px tall) "Javascript disabled" warning.
However, I get a flash of the Javascript warning before the rest of the content loads, even though I have Javascript enabled in my browser. How can I delay the "Javascript disabled" warning from appearing, say for 3 seconds? Is there a way I can mimic jQuery's "slideDown" method when I do display it?

Comment: Really? Just use `<noscript>`. If your users have JS disabled, **they don't want** (or their browser can't support) your fancy-schmancy delay.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a great example for that. You can make the banner go away if you want, and it's not-obtrusive.

Comment: I was under the impression that noscript is an inelegant and dated solution - is it, in fact, still being used? Can I use it inside the <body> tag?

Comment: Isn't `noscript.js` a bit of an oxymoron? And, no, `<noscript>` is **just fine**. In fact, [in HTML5 it was even extended](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-noscript-element) to be valid inside the `<head>` element. So I don't know where you got the impression that it's somehow socially deprecated; that's certainly not the case as far as I can tell.

Comment: BTW I can't stress enough how _right_ Matt Ball is. Please for the love of god don't pursue this concept any further, daysrunaways!

Comment: I would like to point out that there *are* problems with <noscript>. It is not supported in XHTML, and it only displays if *all* scripts are disabled, but not if one specific script fails to load. This specific load failure might be a javascript error, or it might be a user-specified browser configuration (for example, with the NoScript addon for Firefox). The HTML5 Spec says: "The noscript element is a blunt instrument... it's generally better to avoid using noscript, and to instead design the script to change the page from being a scriptless page to a scripted page on the fly..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah i will have to agree with Matt Ball, just use `<noscript>`. it is so much more simple.

Also im not even sure if thats possible without javascript lol